# Add custom buttons to WooCommerce products for specific attributes and terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

For a website with WooCommerce I need to add buttons to the single-product page when the product has a certain attribute + value. In this case: when the product has attribute `pa_aanbod` add buttons, and when the product has the attribute value `Verhuur`, add another button.

I got this far by making the class shown below. The problem with this is that when I add another random attribute to the product, the button group is being duplicated, so with every newly added attribute, an extra button group is being added.

My question is: how can i make sure that the button group is only being added once, and not being duplicated when adding additional attributes to the product? I think it has to do with the `foreach` statement, but I am not really sure on how to solve this.

```
if (!class_exists('WcAddFormButtons')) {

class WcAddFormButtons
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', array( $this, 'single_product_add_formbuttons', ), 50);

    }

    /**
     * Check the terms of product taxonomy pa_aanbod
     * to get the right buttons associated with the forms
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function single_product_add_formbuttons()
    {

        global $product;
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $product_title = get_the_title( $product->get_id() );

        if ( ! $attributes ) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

            // skip variations
            if ($attribute['is_variation']) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($attribute['is_taxonomy']) {

                $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'pa_aanbod');

                echo '<div class="button-group">';

                    foreach ($terms as $term) :

                        switch ($term->name) {

                            case 'Verhuur' :
                                echo '<a class="vc_general vc_btn vc_btn-style-normal vc_btn-color-main-brand-color full-width" href="' . site_url() . '/direct-huren/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Direct huren</a>';
                                break;
                        }

                    endforeach;

                    echo '<a class="vc_general vc_btn vc_btn-style-normal vc_btn-color-main-brand-color full-width" href="' . site_url() . '/offerte-aanvragen/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Offerte aanvragen</a>';

                    echo '<a class="ask-demo" href="' . site_url() . '/demo-aanvragen/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Demo aanvragen</a>';

                echo '</div>';
            }

        endforeach;

    }

}
new WcAddFormButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code to avoid the repetition, when an additional attribute is added:

```
if (!class_exists('WcAddFormButtons')) {

class WcAddFormButtons
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', array( $this, 'single_product_add_formbuttons', ), 50);

    }

    /**
     * Check the terms of product taxonomy pa_aanbod
     * to get the right buttons associated with the forms
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function single_product_add_formbuttons()
    {

        global $product;

        ## -- Set HERE below your product attribute taxonomy and term name -- ##
        $taxonomy = 'pa_aanbod';
        $term_name = 'Verhuur';

        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $product_title = get_the_title( $product->get_id() );

        if ( ! $attributes ) return;

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

            $attribute_data = $attribute->get_data();

            if ( $attribute_data['variation'] != 1 && $attribute_data['is_taxonomy'] == 1 && $attribute_data['name'] == $taxonomy ) {

                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );

                echo '<div class="button-group">';

                foreach( $terms as $term ) if( $term->name == $term_name ) {

                    echo '<a class="vc_general vc_btn vc_btn-style-normal vc_btn-color-main-brand-color full-width" href="' . site_url() . '/direct-huren/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Direct huren</a>';
                        break;
                }

                echo '<a class="vc_general vc_btn vc_btn-style-normal vc_btn-color-main-brand-color full-width" href="' . site_url() . '/offerte-aanvragen/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Offerte aanvragen</a>';

                echo '<a class="ask-demo" href="' . site_url() . '/demo-aanvragen/?makkina_machine_name=' . $product_title . '">Demo aanvragen</a>';

                echo '</div>';
            }

        endforeach;

    }

}
new WcAddFormButtons();
}
```

This code is tested and work.